# mysql small issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying following query...

```
SELECT b.name AS batch_name, b.id AS batch_id,
COUNT( s.id ) AS total_students,
COALESCE( sum(s.open_bal), 0 ) AS open_balance,
sum( COALESCE(i.reg_fee,0) + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,0) + COALESCE(i.other_fee,0) ) AS gross_fee  
FROM batches b
LEFT JOIN students s on s.batch = b.id
LEFT JOIN invoices i on i.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY b.name, b.id;
```

result set

```
| batch_name | batch_id  | total_students | open_balance | gross_fee |
+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+
|  ba        | 11        | 44             | 0            | 1782750   |
+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+
```

But its giving unexpted results, and if i remove `sum( COALESCE(i.reg_fee,0) + COALESCE(i.tut_fee,0) + COALESCE(i.other_fee,0) ) AS gross_fee`  and `LEFT JOIN fm_invoices i on i.student_id = s.id`, it gives expected/correct results as following...

```
| batch_name | batch_id  | total_students | open_balance | gross_fee |
+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+
|  ba        | 11        | 34             | 0            | 0         |
+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I am sure, i am doing something and i am trying every option since last hour, please help.

Comment: @ajreal Why does COUNT(s.id) return 44 in the first query and 34 in the second query, and how can I make it count 34 students while I sum the invoices in the same query?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is something like:

> Why does `COUNT(s.id)` return 44 in the first query and 34 in the second query, and how can I make it count 34 students while I sum the invoices in the same query?

You have multiple invoices for some of your students, and the join results in multiple rows with the same `s.id`.  When you count them, it counts each of these multiple rows.

You should use `COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)` to make the query count each student id only once, even when it appears multiple times as a consequence of the join to invoices.

---

Re your question about what to change, just change `COUNT(s.id)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)`.  The rest of the query looks fine, if I have a correct understanding of what you want it to do.

Comment: do you take projects? i need you for some more mysql help.

Comment: Yes, I work for Percona Inc. as a MySQL performance consultant.  You can contact us here:  http://www.percona.com/mysql-consulting/overview/

Comment: i just need help with some mysql query, so please give me yours email, ready to pay.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't do that because of my agreement with my employer.